# How to ignore brackets in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that takes a template literal and then matches it against a CSV of conditions and links.

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^${condition},\/.+`, 'gi');
```

For example, the variable *Sore throat* would match

```
'Sore throat,/conditions/sore-throat/'
```

I've come across an issue where the template literal might contain brackets and therefore the regex no longer matches. So *Diabetes (type 1)* doesn't match

```
'Diabetes (type 1),/conditions/type-1-diabetes/'
```

I've tried removing the brackets and it's contents from the template literal but there are some cases where the brackets aren't always at the end of the string. Such as, *Lactate dehydrogenase (LDH) test*

```
'Lactate dehydrogenase (LDH) test,/conditions/ldh-test/'
```

I'm not too familiar with regex so apologies if this is simple but I haven't been able to find a way to escape the brackets without knowing exactly where they will be in the string, which in my case isn't possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable that might contain special characters as part of a regex string, but you /don't/ want those special characters to be interpreted using their "regex" meaning. I'm not aware of any native way to do this in Javascript regex - in Perl, you would use `\Q${condition}\E`, but that doesn't seem to be supported.

Instead, you should escape your condition variable before passing it into the regex, using a function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex):

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

Comment: Not by me but probably because you _cut'n pasted_ the _Short and Sweet_ answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex when it is should just be a comment.